# Django request not logging

Tags: django, python-2.7, logging

I'm very confused.  I've searched through many similar threads and tried all of the proposed solutions and nothing works.

I'm trying to setup logging in my Django application.  I can get any direct logger calls (logger.error() etc) to write to my file from the application or the console, but the django.request simply won't write.  On startup both files are created and have correct permissions.  I've tried django-requestlogging and multiple other things, changing disable exisiting loggers, propagate etc and nothing works.  This is my logging setup right now:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/srv/hawthorn/logs/debug.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
    'request_file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/srv/hawthorn/logs/request.log',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
},
'loggers': {

    'django.request': {
        'handlers':['request_file'],

        'level':'INFO',
    },
    'audio': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
}
```

If I even try to change the logfile path to relative, like 'logs/debug.log' the file gets created but stops getting written to (has the correct permissions).  My project looks like:

```
hawthorn/
   audio/   (views are here)
   admin/
   hawthorn/   (settings.py is here)
```

Interesting note that almost any configuration works when trying from the python console.  I could get django-requestlogging from the console (at least calling logger.info() ) but not from hitting my app in a browser (which also calls logger.info() ).

I'm running Django 1.6.1 and python 2.7.6

What am I missing??  All I want is a log of the requests as they come in. I'd really appreciate the help.

Calling it like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

then just logger.debug("test") in the view.
```

EDIT:

So, turns out the requests are being logged to the request.log file, but only warning and errors.  I changed all levels of the config to debug, why won't it log all requests?

Comment: Can you add some code for how you're trying to use the logger. Please include how you import it and set it up.

Comment: The usual,

    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Then in the view just logger.debug("test").

Like I said, this part works.  Any specified logger.whatever call writes to the file, but I want all requests to go to the request file.

SO, I found out that it is actually logging to request.log but only when it's Warning or Error.  It's set to Debug, how come not all requests are getting logged?

Comment: You may want to include 'werkzeug' logger in loggings. It could be disabled. Check out https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/787